# How to use Lua in NIFi's ExecuteScript?

Tags: redis, lua, apache-nifi

How do I use Lua scripts with nIFi's ExecuteScript processor

I have tested lua on Linux

```
[root@localhost bin]# /sdb1/services/redis-4.0.10/bin/redis-cli -h 192.168.50.209 -p 6379 eval "return redis.call('HGET',KEYS[1],KEYS[2])" 2 demo 1144
```

"{device_id:1136}"

```
[root@localhost bin]# /sdb1/services/redis-4.0.10/bin/redis-cli -h 192.168.50.209 -p 6379 eval "return redis.call('HGET',KEYS[1],KEYS[2])" 2 demo 1144
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Lua might not be the easiest scripting language to use in NiFi's ExecuteScript, but it is possible to write scripts in [LuaJ](http://www.luaj.org/luaj.html) using the NiFi API to work on FlowFiles and ProcessSessions and such (but if you're using Redis that part will be up to you :) I wrote a [blog post](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2017/03/lua-and-executescript-in-nifi-revisited.html) about it and we have a trivial [unit test](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-scripting-bundle/nifi-scripting-processors/src/test/resources/lua/test_onTrigger.lua) as another example. I didn't add it to my [cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) because I didn't know how many people were going to use it. Perhaps I'll update that to include LuaJ examples.

Comment: Thank you very much, Actually, I want to store the data in REIDS in the hash mode, but the existing Redis processor does not have the Hset mode, do you have a better way?